# RDLC details columns between two gouping columns

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-grouping

How to put details columns between two grouping columns as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a nested table.

1. Create two tables. One is the outer table with an empty column where the PO Number will go. The other is just a list of PO Numbers.

[image]

2. Drag the PO Number table into the details line in the main table.

[image]

Here is a sample of it working:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response please send me the .rdl file. I'm confused how to make a relationship between the tables!

Comment: It's working! just put the details table in the grouping table without any configuration!